# Is it possible to send a secured mail with out the credentials of the sender?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle

I am trying to send digital signed/secrured mail using JavaMAIL API.

For this i created KEYSTORE certificate and used (loaded through bouncycastle) this while generating this mail and sending it to the user. But i have to provide user name and password of the sender mail id to authenticate.

Is there any way to send  secured mail with out the credentials of the sender?

I tried by making authentication as false. but no luck.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
```

My Code :::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String fromEmail = "satishkumar.reddy@xyz.com"; //requires valid gmail id
    final String toEmail = "satishxxxxxreddy@gmail.com";



    System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "132.000.000.001"); //SMTP Host
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
     props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("MYUSERNAME","MYPASSWORD");
                   }
                });

    boolean isAlias = false;


     //Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

     System.out.println("SESSION CREATED..............");

            try {

              // Add BouncyCastle content handlers to command map
                MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
                mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");
                CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcap);

                Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

                // Provide location of Java Keystore and password for access
                keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\CERTIFICATES\\MAIL_CERT\\selfservice.cert"),
                        "keystore".toCharArray());

                // Find the first legit alias in the keystore and use it
                Enumeration<String> es = keyStore.aliases();
                String alias = "";
                while (es.hasMoreElements()) {
                    alias = (String) es.nextElement();

                    // Does alias refer to a private key? Assign true/false to isAlias & evaluate
                    if (isAlias = keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isAlias) {
                    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("keystore".toCharArray()));
                    PrivateKey myPrivateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();

                    // Load certificate chain
                    Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

                    // Create the SMIMESignedGenerator
                    SMIMECapabilityVector capabilities = new SMIMECapabilityVector();
                    capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_EDE3_CBC);
                    capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.rC2_CBC, 128);
                    capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_CBC);
                    capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES256_CBC);

                    ASN1EncodableVector attributes = new ASN1EncodableVector();
                    attributes.add(new SMIMEEncryptionKeyPreferenceAttribute(
                            new IssuerAndSerialNumber(
                            new X500Name(((X509Certificate) chain[0])
                            .getIssuerDN().getName()),
                            ((X509Certificate) chain[0]).getSerialNumber())));
                    attributes.add(new SMIMECapabilitiesAttribute(capabilities));

                    SMIMESignedGenerator signer = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
                    signer.addSigner(
                            myPrivateKey,
                            (X509Certificate) chain[0],
                            "DSA".equals(myPrivateKey.getAlgorithm()) ? SMIMESignedGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1
                            : SMIMESignedGenerator.DIGEST_MD5,
                            new AttributeTable(attributes), null);

                    // Add the list of certs to the generator
                    List certList = new ArrayList();
                    certList.add(chain[0]);
                    CertStore certs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                            new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), "BC");
                    signer.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certs);

                    // Construct the message body
                    MimeMessage body = new MimeMessage(session);
                    body.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
                    body.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
                    body.setContent("DEAR.....BODY....", "text/plain");
                    body.saveChanges();


                    // Sign the message
                    MimeMultipart mm = signer.generate(body, "BC");
                    MimeMessage signedMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

                    signedMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
                    signedMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
                    signedMessage.setSubject("Testing Signed Subject");
                    // Set the content of the signed message
                    signedMessage.setContent(mm);
                    signedMessage.saveChanges();

                    // Send the message
                    Transport.send(signedMessage);
                }

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException | UnrecoverableEntryException | 
                    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchProviderException | CertStoreException |SMIMEException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Comment: What error are you facing? The sending of the email is obviously not depending on any credentials other than yours (for SMTP auth), and the encryption would need the receivers public key only (which is hmm **public**.)

Answer (score 0):

The creation of a signed or encrypted email message is completely independent of the ability to login to a mail server and send an email message.  No public email servers are going to let you send an email message without logging in first.  If you have the user's private key to create a signed email message, you're also going to need the user's password to login to the mail server.